# Proving that a set is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Is the following set $A=\{x\in\mathbb R^{n}:||x-z||\le||x-y||,\forall  y\in K, K\subset\mathbb R^{n}  \}$ convex? I need to prove it according to definition.

We have $x_{1},x_{2}\in A, \lambda\in (0,1)$ and we need to show that $\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda) x_{2}\in A$

Since $x_{1},x_{2}\in A$, that is, $||x_{1}-z||\le||x_{1}-y||, ||x_{2}-z||\le||x_{2}-y||$ and we need to prove $||\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda) x_{2}-z||\le||\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda) x_{2}-y||$

$||\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda) x_{2}-z||=||\lambda (x_{1}-z)+(1-\lambda) (x_{2}-z)||\le\lambda||x_{1}-z||+(1-\lambda) ||x_{2}-z||\le \lambda||x_{1}-y||+(1-\lambda)||x_{2}-y||$ Now, I don't know the next steps.

Comment: The set $A$ is "the points $x$ closer to $z$ than they are to $y$, for all $y \in K$". Presumably $z$ is not in $K$?  Is $K$ a convex or compact or both set?

Comment: $K$ is an arbitrary set in $\mathbb{R}$, There's nothing said about $z$. However, it's not important, you are supposed to use the definition of convex set and improve it by calculation.

Comment: Hint: $||x-z||\leq ||x-y||$ is equivalent to $||x-z||^2 \leq ||x-y||^2$.

Comment: I know the hint, but I don't see it useful. There must be something else with Euclidean norm.

Comment: Hint Following @Michael 's hint: it may be helpful that inner product satisfies $\langle x-z\, |\, x-z\rangle = \|x-z\|^2$